# difference between two uncomputable functions

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability

for $L1$ regular language, $L2$ some language, $L1$ \ $L2$ is regular, decidable. yet, the next transition function might not even be computable:

$F′=${$\,q:δ(q,w)∈F \, for\, some\, w∈ L2\,$}$.$

$F$ is the accepting states group of DFA accepting $L1$.
$F'$ is the accepting states group of DFA accepting $L1$ \ $L2$

$HALT\,=${$<M,w>|M\,is\, a\, TM\, and\, M\, halts\, on\, w\,$}

$
on (M,w):\,
return\, 1\, is\, M\, halts\, on\, w\,
\,
return\, 0\, else\,
$

this function is also well defined, but not computable. 
We know that the halting problem isn't decidable. what is the difference? In both cases the functions are well defined, but the first case is decidable, and the second isn't.

Comment: The difference is that $F'$ is a finite object, whereas the function *on* is an infinite object. So you can hardwire $F'$ into the code of a Turing machine, but can't do the same for *on*.

Comment: you mean that {<M,w>| on(<M,w>)=1} is infinite?

Comment: That's right. There is (provably) no finite way to store all information in *on* so that it can be recovered in a computable way. No such issues arise in $F'$.